# Getting the primary key after row insertion using redshift

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

I'm using postgresql 8.0.2 with amazon redshift and I'm trying to set up a `INSERT` command that also returns the `PRIMARY KEY`.

I was originally trying to do the following:

```
with get_connection() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO orders (my_id, my_amount) \
                 VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING row_id;', (some_id, some_amount))
    conn.commit()
```

However, the `RETURNING` command only works on postgresql 8.2 and above.

I saw that `currval` might be a possible way to get this to work, but I read that it requires a sequence object.

I'm trying to insert the following schema

```
CREATE SEQUENCE order_seq;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders
(
    order_id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY DISTKEY, 
)
```

Then do:

```
with get_connection() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO orders (my_id, my_amount) \
                     VALUES (%s, %s);', (some_id, some_amount))
        conn.commit()
        cur.execute('SELECT currval();')
        row_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

UPDATE: Sequence objects are not supported by redshift either.  I feel like this is a pretty basic procedure but there is no easy way to get a reference to the current row.

Answer (score 1):

Just define your column as:

```
order_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DISTKEY
```

And with your sequence created `order_seq` use this as insert command:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO orders (order_id, my_id, my_amount) \
                 VALUES (nextval(''order_seq''), %s, %s);', (some_id, some_amount))
```

Since you are using a sequence you have to add the field on the insert command to use the `nextval` properly.

And to retrieve current sequence value do as follow:

```
cur.execute('SELECT currval(''order_seq'')')
row_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

I'm not familirized with the language you are using so you may have to change the syntaxe to scape the double quotes I use.

The syntaxe of `nextval` and `currval` is like: `nextval('sequenceName')` and `currval('sequenceName')`

So if it does not support `sequences` the only way I see that it could solve your issue is following this steps:

1. Open a transaction (so others wont get the same id)
2. fetch max id of your table like `select max(order_id) from orders` into a variable
3. use this value on the insert as it was the sequence.

Comment: Correct, but caution leaving the trailing `;` in the select query; some drivers choke on them.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think i might have confused you.  I'm sending two values to store in the database.  some_id is actually the ID of a transaction and some_amount is the amount of the transaction.

Comment: @Brosef there you are. Since the nextval is a database function you can call it directly on your sql command.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Should the conn.commit() go between the cur.execute('INSERT') and cur.execute('SELECT')?

Comment: Oh man, it looks like sequences aren't supported by redshift either!  so currval isn't an option. Any other way to go about this?

Comment: I've edited with an alternative, let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102943/discussion-between-brosef-and-jorge-campos).